# Response Curves for binary part of Zero-Inflated model R

Tags: r

I've plotted the response curves for each of my predictors against all of predicted values to determine how each predictor influences my counts. However, I also want to plot the binary part of my zero-inflated model to see how the predictors in the binary part of the zero-inflated model help explain the probability of false zeroes. I am trying to get a plot similar to the one at the bottom of the page of the link below however they don't provide reproducible code in that example.

https://fukamilab.github.io/BIO202/04-C-zero-data.html#sketch_fitted_and_predicted_values

I've included some code below where I have my zero-inflated model and the predictors used. I then use the predict function to predict the estimates for a much larger raster grid (new.data) and I want to see the response between those predicted values and the predictors I use across the entire raster grid.

```
mod1 = zeroinfl(Response~x1+x2|x1,link ="logit",data=data, 
                          dist="negbin")
modpred=predict(mod1, new.data, se.fit=T, type = "response")

response1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x1, y = modpred)) + geom_point()+
  +geom_smooth(data = data, aes(x = x1, y = modpred))
```

Comment: You are much more likely to receive a useful answer if you provide a reproducible example.